# Insert into select statement with two where conditions

Tags: sql

I have two similar tables in SQL. FixedDetails and TempFixedDetails. Now i want to update the 2nd row of TempFixedDetails from fixeddetails.Can anyone help me with the query?

Fixed details:

```
ID  Itemdescription   Date
1   Lenovo           4/9/2014
2   Idea             5/7/2015
```

TempFixed Details :

```
ID  Itemdescription Date
1   Lenovo          4/9/2014
2   Null             null
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: You could go to google and search for keyword `SQL update from select`. Try it, you will find it easy to write yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `ID` column in `tempfixed_details` is unique, you can do the following:

You didn't mention your DBMS, so the following is standard ANSI SQL:

```
update tempfixed_details
   set (itemdescription, date) = (select fd.itemdescription, fd.date
                                  from  fixed_details fd
                                  where tempfixed_details.id = fd.id)
where itemdescription is null
  and date is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below using join

```
       update TempFixedDetailst t2 set t2.Itemdescription=t1.Itemdescription, t2.Date=t1.Date
        INNER JOIN  
Fixeddetails t1 on t2.id=ti.id
```

Comment: Standard SQL does not allow a `FROM` clause or a join in the UPDATE statement. You should at least mention the DBMS product for which your solution works (currently the question has no DBMS specific tag)